# Prove that $a^x \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$ if and only if $k \mid 2x$ but $k \nmid x$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $k = \text{ord}_p(a)$ where $p$ is an odd prime. Prove that $a^x \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$ if and only if $k \mid 2x$ but $k \nmid x$.

I was wondering how to prove this statement. How do we prove both directions?

Comment: Can you prove either direction?

Comment: (Presumable, $p$ is an odd prime.)

Answer (score 1):

Lets first assume that $k\mid 2x$ but $k\nmid x$.
Now we have that there exists a $t$ such that $2x=kt$. So now we have $a^{2x}\equiv a^{kt}\equiv 1 \pmod{p}\Rightarrow (a^x-1)(a^x+1)\equiv0\pmod{p}$.
If it was true that $a^x\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ we would have that $k\mid x$, but this isn't true so we have that $a^x\equiv-1\pmod{p}$.

Assume now that $a^x\equiv -1\pmod{p}$. From squaring the expression we get $a^{2x}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ so now we have that $k\mid 2x$. If we would have that $k$ divides $x$ we would have that $a^x\equiv1\equiv-1\pmod{p}\Rightarrow 2\equiv0\pmod{p}$, so we would have $p=2$. Otherwise you would have that $k\nmid x$.

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP has proved or knows that if $a^m\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ for some $n\ge 2$, $m\ge 1$, $n,m,a\in\mathbb Z$, then $\text{ord}_n(a)\mid m$.

Comment: The proof is simple: if, for contradiction, $m=\text{ord}_n(a)k+r$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$, $k\ge 0$, $\text{ord}_n(a)> r> 0$, then $a^{m}\equiv \left(a^{\text{ord}_n(a)}\right)^k\cdot a^r\equiv 1^k\cdot a^r\equiv a^r\not\equiv 1\pmod{n}$.